# Finding probability or volume of a set of points satisfying an inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-theory, convex-analysis, systems-of-equations

I wish to find the probability (or volume) of points satisfying an inequality.

Consider the following parameters.

$w = [w_1,w_2,w_3,w_4]^T, w \in \mathbb{R}^4$ and Bias $b \in \mathbb{R}$. The $w$ and $b$ are fixed.

$x = [x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]^T$. Each $x_i \in [l_i,u_i]$ where $l_i, u_i \in \mathbb{R}$. $x$ is the variable.

I wish to find the probability (or volume) of points $x$ that satisfy the following inequality-

$0 \leq w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3 + b < -w_4 $

Something that bounds the probability (or volume) will also work.
Maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Volume) helps, but I am not sure how to use it.

Clarifications-

1. $x_4$ disappears due to the structure of my specific use case.
2. I need a closed form to write in a theorem.

Edit-
So the 2 hyperplanes defined by $0 \leq w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3 + b$ and $w_1x_1 + w_2x_2 + w_3x_3 + b < -w_4 $ are parallel to each other. So the question boils down to finding the volume of the resulting high dimension shape..

Comment: You are right! I'll delete my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

After suitable scaling of the sides on the box in which $x$ resides, you reduce to the case of the unit box, and a newly scaled version of $w$.
Then you essentially just want the  volume of the region obtained by cutting the unit cube with a tilted plane whose unit normal is $N$, retaining the portion where $N\cdot x>c$. For fixed $N$,  and box dimension three, this is in general a piece-wise cubic polynomial function of the parameter $c$, which is rather cumbersome to write down. One way to hand off the problem to a computer algebra system is to have it compute a multivariable Laplace transform. You could practice with the 2D version of the problem first to get some insight into that method.

P.S. Somehow $x_4$ disappeared from your problem, and I suspect that is something you need to clarify.
[image]

Comment: $x_4$ disappears due to the structure of my use case. I have added to the question, thanks!I needed a closed form since I have to use in a theorem..

Comment: One interesting fact is that the 2 hyperplanes (defined by the 2 inequalities) are parallel to each other.